# MongoDB - How to handle hundred thousands of concurrent connections?

Tags: database, mongodb, connection, database-connection, mongodb-atlas

I'm setting up a MongoDB-Atlas Database and currrently use the Free Tier with 100 concurrent connections. This is fine for now, but our team wants to expand on this and possibly serve hundreds of thousands of connections.

The M400 Tier of MongoDB-Atlas offers 128.000 concurrent connections, however every client uses about 5 connections at once which brings us to a maximum of 25.600 conncurent connections.

So my question is how do big services like Twitter, Discord, etc. handle connection numbers in the range of Millions? Is it even possible to achieve this with MongoDB-Atlas?

Comment: Twitter, Discord, etc don't use a database connection for every single user on the site, not to mention they would be in a completely different league to any system you are likely to be working on for a while. Odds are that a majority of web sites around the world would really be hard pressed at utilizing anything more than 100 concurrent connections per application server instance. Since we would be talking sub-second response times ( ideally ) then that's quite reasonably 300 requests through the database per second, or approx 500k requests per second on the M400 tier. More than enough.

Comment: Any approaches, my friend?

Comment: Actually yes, the answer is quite simple actually. You set up an intermediary server between your database and your clients. This server will connect to your db and provide an API for your clients. The server will be able to handle thousands of concurrent requests at once and should you need more, you just add another server.